# Take photos allows me to select more than maxNumberOfSelections in BSImagePicker Swift ios

Tags: swift, image, swift3

Here is my code

```
 let vc = BSImagePickerViewController()
    vc.takePhotos = true
    vc.maxNumberOfSelections = 2

    bs_presentImagePickerController(vc, animated: true,
                                    select: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in
                                        print("Selected: \(asset)")
    }, deselect: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in
        print("Deselected: \(asset)")
    }, cancel: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
        print("Cancel: \(assets)")
    }, finish: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
        print("Finish: \(assets)")
        print(assets.count)
        for i in 0..<assets.count
        {
            self.SelectedAssets.append(assets[i])
            print(self.SelectedAssets)
        }
    }, completion: nil)
```

If I select 2 photos and click on the camera, then it allows me to take a picture and a new picture marked as "3", which is more than the maximum number of selections defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a bug in `BSImagePickerViewController` as the maximum number of selections is not checked while presenting the `imagePicker` with `.camera`. So, you can change/unlock the pod locally by adding the condition in `PhotosViewController` at line `287` as below,

```
    // Camera shouldn't be selected, but pop the UIImagePickerController!
    let isAllowedToTakePicture = (photosDataSource?.selections.count ?? 0) < settings.maxNumberOfSelections
    if let composedDataSource = composedDataSource , composedDataSource.dataSources[indexPath.section].isEqual(cameraDataSource), isAllowedToTakePicture {
        let cameraController = UIImagePickerController()
        cameraController.allowsEditing = false
        cameraController.sourceType = .camera
        cameraController.delegate = self

        self.present(cameraController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You can also fork this Library and make a pull request with this fix so that the moderators can merge your fix.

The above fix will be temporary and it can appear again if you made `pod install/update` until it is not merged in original library.